# Flat list to composite object

Tags: java, dozer, modelmapper

Is there a way to convert, flattened  DTO arrays to composite nested objects.

Currently I'm using modelmapper for domain to domain conversion.

```
   class SourceList {
    List<Integer> id;

    List<String> name;
}

class DestinationList {
    List<Person> name;
}

class Person {
    Integer id;

    String name;
}
```

The data will be there in denormalized way, I need to convert to the proper nested structure. DTO to composite object conversion i'm able to do that using [modelmapper](http://modelmapper.org/getting-started/).

I want to convert source list to destination list automatically. Since manual conversion is not a viable option in the long run.
I'm also interested in dozer if it is possible.

Comment: I don't know what a flat list is, but I do know that this is flat code.

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux Since I'm using solr   to store the multivalued fields, I need to de-normalize the values this way.

Comment: @hariweton: I'm really sorry but I do not know what you were talking about. With "flat code", I was mentioning that you did not put any indentation. It was rather a joke. As I already mentioned: I really do not know what you are trying. I'm not familiar with the subject.

Comment: I just typed the code on the editor itself so i'm not able to indent properly. No issues